# Increase the time of the pmset countdown

Tags: shutdown, restart, macos, pmset

Is there a way to change the delay time until a scheduled sleep/restart/shutdown occurs? It starts at 10 minutes (10:00), but I want to change it to 30 minutes (30:00).

[image: Countdown]

As you can see above, the computer is scheduled to restart in 10 minutes via pmset.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there's no way to change this value because a Mac must be **awake for at least 10 minutes past the scheduled time**. It's because of this that the 10 minute value is set and cannot be altered, although I suppose there's no reason why it couldn't be extended beyond that (such as the 30 mins you want). Regardless, I'm not aware that this can be done.

According to Apple:

> To shut down automatically, your Mac must be awake at the time that
>   it's scheduled to shut down, and remain awake for at least 10 minutes
>   past that time. If it's sleeping at the scheduled shutdown time, it
>   continues sleeping instead of shutting down. If it's set to go to
>   sleep after less than 15 minutes of inactivity, it might go back to
>   sleep before it can shut down. To make sure that your Mac shuts down
>   even when sleeping, set it to start up or wake 5 minutes before the
>   scheduled shutdown time.

Source: [Set a startup, wake, sleep, restart, or shutdown time on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201988)

One thing you could do is check the man page for `pmset` on your system to double-check, as different versions of the OS will provide different options (and sometimes particular hardware can offer different options depending on it's type and location).

To check the man page for `pmset` on your system, launch the terminal and enter `man pmset`. Note this may take a while to retrieve the info.